# Is there any way to get in what stash a certain file was added/changed?

Tags: git, git-stash

I know somewhere in my stashes, there is an specific file with some changes I want to recover, but I don't know in which one.

Is there any way to know in what particular stash is this file?. I know about git stash show -p, but that is slow, going through all the stashes and taking a look each one at a time.

Comment: Will this be enough for you a quick one.. Not a perfect solution though
git stash list --name-only | egrep '^stash@|<filename>'

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
git stash list
```

> The command takes options applicable to the git log command to control
>   what is shown and how.

So, you can use any of the following to see which stash has the changes,

```
git stash list --name-only
```

or

```
git stash list --name-status
```

or

```
git stash list --stat
```

or

```
git stash list -p #To see the changes in all the stashes together along with the diff
```

**Update:**

This will list all the stash references in which the given file has been modified.

```
git rev-list -g stash | while read line
do
    if git show $line --name-only --pretty="" | grep --quiet <filename>; then
        echo $line; 
    fi
done
```

Comment: But that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to run a script of sorts that tells me in which stash a particular file is changed, without having to look through them 1 by 1.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'"

Comment: Replace `<filename>` with the actual file name. eg. `git rev-list -g stash | while read line; do if git show $line --name-only --pretty="" | grep --quiet mylostfile.c; then echo $line; fi done`

Comment: Now I get this one: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115848/discussion-between-pratz-and-artemix).